# grunt-jade - how to compile single jade file instead of everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gruntjs, pug

I have the following in my jade.js file

```
'use strict';

var config = require('../config');

module.exports = {
  dist: {
    options: {
    pretty: true,
    debug: false,
    timestamp: '<%= new Date().getTime() %>'
  },
  files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'html_templates/views/',
    src: '**/*.jade',
    dest: 'html_templates/html/',
    ext: '.html'
  }]
 }
};
```

It is working great ! The only problem is that, i am working on a very large application and my jade files are over 10mb. When i modify the view of one jade file and run 'grunt jade'. It recompiles all my html (takes about 5 minutes). How to i tell grunt to only compile the relevant jade file(only one html file)

Example: I am working on:

```
html_templates/views/module/landingpage2.jade
```

I want to compile only:

```
html_templates/html/module/landingpage1.html
```

Please help

Comment: There are solutions for this problem. From the top of my head, "grunt newer" deals with this by checking which files were updated and only processing these files.

Comment: I am also looking to add this to grunt watch. Have you tested this with watch?

Comment: Yes, I use watch. You can use the "watch" event to identify the file that changed and then dynamically set that path in the grunt jade config. (This is described in the grunt-contrib-watch README.) I'm using the "watch" event for my custom task. See here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/passing-a-value-from-my-gruntfile-to-an-external-grunt-task

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Kudos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grunt-newer`. https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-newer

Just install it and run your task as "newer:jade" and pretty much that's all.

It also works with watch etc.

Comment: Will it work for inherited jade file, I have tried it but no effects :( Any idea or suggestion will be appreciated